# Are Ubuntu upgrades not safe?

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, security

After running `apt update` I noticed that update info is being downloaded using HTTP.

[image]

After running `upgrade`, I see that upgrades are being downloaded from HTTP too.

[image]

My understanding is that HTTP is essentially insecure, i. e. open to intercept and replacement of data. Are the upgrades thus unsafe? Or do I misunderstand something?

Comment: @Zanna thank you very much, that I actually gives me the answer I need.

Comment: excellent :) I think its a common concern